# Difficulties with displaying graphs in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have a problem creating a horizontal segmented bar chart. I must create N bars according to the data I bring from some services and I have a series of problems.

1. The bars start at the end of the X axis, example: the X axis goes from 0 to 100, my bars start at 100.
2. Each object should be an independent bar, but it is not, I think this is the biggest problem and after a week I still have not been able to fix it.

Here is my ReactJS component and a JSON of the preprocessed data object

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useMemo  } from 'react';
import { BarChart, Bar, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend, ResponsiveContainer } from 'recharts';
import MarkLevelService from '../../services/marklevels.service';
import MarkTypeService from '../../services/marktypes.service';

const formatTime = (seconds) => {
  const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  const remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
  return `${String(minutes).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(remainingSeconds).padStart(2, '0')}`;
};

const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload }) => {
  if (active && payload && payload.length) {
    const data = payload[0].payload;
    return (
      <div style={{backgroundColor: 'white', padding: '5px', border: '1px solid #ccc'}}>
        <p>{data.name}</p>
        {data.details.map(detail => (
          <div key={detail.startTime}>
            <p>Start Time: {formatTime(detail.startTime)}</p>
            <p>End Time: {formatTime(detail.endTime)}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
  return null;
};

const GraphChartMarktype = ({ eventData }) => {
  const [processedData, setProcessedData] = useState([]);
  const maxDuration = Math.max(...eventData.map(event => event.video_duration));

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      
      const allData = [];
  
      for (const event of eventData) {
        if (event.mark_level) {
          for (const mark of event.mark_level) {
            const markLevelResponse = await MarkLevelService.get(mark.$oid);
            const markTypeResponse = await MarkTypeService.get(markLevelResponse.data.marktype.$oid);

            if (markLevelResponse.data && markLevelResponse.data.name && markTypeResponse.data.name) {
              allData.push({
                markTypeName: markTypeResponse.data.name,
                markLevelName: markLevelResponse.data.name,
                startTime: event.start_time,
                endTime: event.end_time,
                timeInVideo: event.time_in_video,
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }
  
      const groupedByMarkType = {};
      // console.log(groupedByMarkType);
  
      allData.forEach(data => {
        if (!groupedByMarkType[data.markTypeName]) {
          groupedByMarkType[data.markTypeName] = [];
        }
        groupedByMarkType[data.markTypeName].push(data);
      });
  
      const processed = [];
  
      for (let markTypeName in groupedByMarkType) {
        let segments = groupedByMarkType[markTypeName];
        segments.sort((a, b) => a.startTime - b.startTime);
  
        let barData = {
          name: markTypeName, 
          details: segments.map(segment => ({
            startTime: segment.startTime,
            endTime: segment.endTime,
            markLevelName: segment.markLevelName,
          }))
        };
  
        let lastEndTime = 0;
  
        segments.forEach((segment, index) => {
          if (segment.startTime > lastEndTime) {
            barData[`gap${index}Start`] = lastEndTime;
            barData[`gap${index}`] = segment.startTime - lastEndTime;
            barData[`gap${index}Finish`] = maxDuration - lastEndTime;
          }
  
          barData[`segment${index}`] = segment.endTime - segment.startTime;
  
          lastEndTime = segment.endTime;
        });
  
        processed.push(barData);
      }
  
      setProcessedData(processed);
      console.log(processed);
    };
  
    fetchData();
  }, [eventData]);

  const generateTicks = (maxValue, numberOfTicks) => {
    const step = maxValue / (numberOfTicks - 1);
    return Array.from({ length: numberOfTicks }, (_, i) => Math.round(i * step));
  };
  

  const ticks = generateTicks(maxDuration, 10);  

  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={300}>
      <BarChart
        barGap={5}
        data={processedData}
        layout="vertical"
        margin={{
          top: 20, right: 30, left: 60, bottom: 5,
        }}
      >
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <XAxis 
          type="number" 
          domain={[0, maxDuration]}
          ticks={ticks}
          />
        <YAxis dataKey="name" type="category" />
        <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} />
        <Legend />
        {/* {console.log(processedData)} */}
        {processedData.map((data, dataIndex) => (
          Object.keys(data)
            .filter(key => key.includes("segment") || key.includes("gap"))
            .map((key, index) => {
              const isSegment = key.includes("segment");
              return (
                <Bar 
                  key={`${dataIndex}-${key}`}  // Un key único para cada Bar
                  dataKey={key} 
                  fill={isSegment ? `#${Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)}` : "transparent"} 
                  stackId={"a"}
                  barSize={20} 
                />
              );
            })
        ))}
      </BarChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
}

export default GraphChartMarktype;
```

Obj - JSON

```
[
    {
        "name": "Conversación",
        "details": [
            {
                "startTime": 240,
                "endTime": 369,
                "markLevelName": "Silenciosa"
            }
        ],
        "gap0Start": 0,
        "gap0": 240,
        "gap0Finish": 2191,
        "segment0": 129
    },
    {
        "name": "Interrupción",
        "details": [
            {
                "startTime": 240,
                "endTime": 369,
                "markLevelName": "Moderada"
            },
            {
                "startTime": 1053,
                "endTime": 1101,
                "markLevelName": "Baja"
            }
        ],
        "gap0Start": 0,
        "gap0": 240,
        "gap0Finish": 2191,
        "segment0": 129,
        "gap1Start": 369,
        "gap1": 684,
        "gap1Finish": 1822,
        "segment1": 48
    },
    {
        "name": "Colaboración",
        "details": [
            {
                "startTime": 240,
                "endTime": 369,
                "markLevelName": "Alta"
            },
            {
                "startTime": 1053,
                "endTime": 1101,
                "markLevelName": "Baja"
            }
        ],
        "gap0Start": 0,
        "gap0": 240,
        "gap0Finish": 2191,
        "segment0": 129,
        "gap1Start": 369,
        "gap1": 684,
        "gap1Finish": 1822,
        "segment1": 48
    }
]
```

[image: Current operation]